# Как из нескольких ArrayList-ов данные показать в одном ListView так, чтобы данные не перемешались?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Пытаюсь сделать List Adapter.

У меня есть 2 аррайлиста, в одном содержатся шведские слова, в другом их переводы (swedishList и russianList).
Содержимое листов меняется по ходу прохождения приложения.
Слова эти по очереди высвечиваются игроку, чтобы он их повторял и проверял перевод.

Задача в том, чтобы создать ListView со Switch-ами, в котором бы в каждом item-e
показывалось бы шведское слово и его русский перевод, а также тумблер Switch, отключив который
игрок бы "отключал" слово, чтобы оно больше не показывалось в игре.

При этом "отключение" слова отжатием Switch должно переносить слово в другой,
в новый swedishHideList и russianHideList соответственно, но при этом чтобы слово
продолжало показываться в ListView чтобы его снова можно было "включить".

Как сделать, чтобы в одном пункте ЛистВью показывались слово и его аналог из разных АррайЛистов?
В идеале хотелось бы как-то сначала объединить их, как-то "сцепить" каждое шведское слово с его переводом,
а потом сделать чтобы в ЛистВью они отображались в алфавитном порядке (относительно шведских слов).

Получается, что ListView должен состоять из 4 АррайЛистов:

1)swedishList + 2)russianList, а также
3)swedishHideList + 4)russianHideList

... но так, чтобы переводы соответствовали словам, и чтобы все вместе было в алфавитном
порядке (относительно шведского словаря).

Comment: Нельзя сделать свой класс со всеми флагами/перводами и сделать массив  такого класса? И переиспользовать этот массив сколько надо раз?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте задумался о использовании RecyclerView
А так бы, предложил бы создать третий list, в цикле for : list.add( shvedList.get(i) + " " + rusList.add(i)) , и данный ,заполненный лист через адаптер.